# Test for the convergence of a series with cos(n*pi/4) help?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would I find the convergence of a series such as this one?  This is from the Alternating Series Test homework that I'm working on, so I assume that I have to somehow use the Alternating Series Test, but I can't figure out how.
$$\sum_{n=0}^n\frac{3}{n+1}cos(\frac{n\pi}{4})$$

Comment: Welcome the Mathematics Stack Exchange community. A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site  will help you get the most of your time here.

Comment: If it is not allowed to use the Dirichlet test, then remove the zero terms and group the remaining terms in three of the same sign